# how use while in var_dump for telegram bot

Tags: php, variables, while-loop, telegram-bot, var-dump

```
<?php
    $res_best=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM best");
    $best=array();
    while($best=mysql_fetch_assoc($res_best)){
        $best['username'];
    }
    var_dump(
        makeHTTPRequest('sendMessage',[
            'chat_id'=>$chat_id,
            'text'=>$best
        ])
    );
?>
```

I want save while in variable and use this variable in var_dump for telegram bot.
how can i use this while for text?

Comment: While this won't fix your problem, please note the `mysql_` constructor is [**deprecated as of PHP 5.5**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), and is [**removed in PHP 7**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql). Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) :)

Comment: `var_dump()` is for debugging, it's not generally useful in applications.

Comment: What is the line `$best['username'];` supposed to do?

Comment: You should probably put the `makeHTTPRequest()` call inside the `while` loop.